# My sweater has got lint balls on it, take them off/remove them?

Tags: word-usage

[image]
<sup>(image from Reddit.com)</sup>

What is a natural way to express it? I mean, my mom says:

> "You shouldn't sleep with your sweater on, or it'll **get lint balls (or fuzzballs).**

So is the use of "get" natural? If not, what can be a natural alternative to be used in this context?

And what about:

> I will tell you how to **remove/take off** lint balls.

Is the use of "take off" instead of "remove" natural?

Answer (score 1):

Both *to get* and *to remove* work nicely with *lint balls*.

> **To remove the lint balls**, use a fabric shaver.
>
> You don't have to dye it and walk around with nasty lint balls in your locs, **simply remove it**.
>
> Graze the material with the razor **to remove the lint balls**.
>
> After awhile they **get these lint balls on** them.
>
> My clothes are not **getting those lint balls on** them.
>
> They also **get those little lint balls** after too many washes.

I am not sure about *to take off*, but *to get off* seems to be commonly used.

You could also use *get rid of*.

Answer (score 1):

Small balls of fibers that form on some, usually knit fabrics are also called [pills](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pill). 'Pill' is also [a verb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pill#h46976331211940) for the formation of such balls, and the verb for removing them is ["depill"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/depill)  (also de-pill).

So, you may know [how to depill/de-pill a sweater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BU5ie9OyAp0)/to get pills off a sweater, or  [to remove pilling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D386PUzArdA)/lint balls/sweater pills. As for the sweater you don't take off lying on the sofa, it'll pill in no time.

Comment: And can I use: Do you know how to "take off" these lint balls?  Is the use of "take off" natural instead of "remove"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish -Personally to me, take off is associated with a flat surface--planes take off and land, or the clothes I take off. [See here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-off_1)

Answer (score 0):

It will "attract" them? It will "form" them? They will "result"? I don't know if a "get" (an acquisition) is necessarily as appropriate as a "happened to" (a consequence).

Your sweater will wind up covered in them, either way.

Comment: Are you asking or stating these alternatives? As it stands, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133425)